# Cisco ASA: How to modify a logging list that is in use?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

When attempting to modify/remove a logging list on a Cisco ASA 5545, I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: Can not modify logging list LOGGING_TEST while in use
```

What steps are required to modify/remove a logging list that is "in use"?

Comment: "_How can I modify/remove a logging list that is "in use"?_" You can't; you need to stop using it first.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified the question - I'm looking for the required steps to modify/remove a logging list that is currently in use.

Comment: Right, but you need to stop using it, then remove it or modify it and start using it again.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not being clear. From the error message, I understand that you cannot modify a logging list while it is use. However, I need to modify this logging list. Therefore, I need to stop using it in order to proceed with modifying it. I do not know how to do this, and am hoping somebody that does could provide some pointers on how to do so. I hope that's more clear.

Comment: You have one or more command which use the logging list. You need to find any commands which use the logging list, and disable the use of the logging list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the logging trap first using the command,

no logging  trap LOGGING_TEST

Then modify the logging list and at last enable the logging trap using the command,

logging  trap LOGGING_TEST

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
logging mail LOGGING_TEST2
logging list LOGGING_TEST message 722041
logging list LOGGING_TEST message 722051
logging mail LOGGING_TEST
```